# Django cant save file locally ([Errno 13] Permission denied)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am using the django package django-facebook, which runs into an error when it attempts to save ta user's profile picture locally.
I am running Apache and have tried chown'ing the folder to www-data, have tried chmod'ing permissions to a+w, however the error still prevails

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.dancefund.com/facebook/connect/?attempt=1&code=AQBPcL0lR4bDzIEA0r-TOiHQzpJ21L_mUTgN0GB98E7lg1C9FFvfCz0vAUQiDMsVx3ppVHOngdsYp5OX0tR1gIIfsNp9aBOZc15DYR78vdasD5cg25Nl7Xr5Q9T98y1-6afC-htBzI1IeNwXcpXlqjgHRlEQqRk1vk9Da62LS1nSwXkiCRmoz8on1PLJhXOvRL6aWm9FeOUvPLLob0xA3_jZslw3m3RX01WF2MM1LGEMWkhkQdaxeKN3OzdM7O6FX8IvRfYrhPFK1fTch8PVtqX_0I2ZLZh6m7syX943T9nvwMWwrhi4YeI5kHjU7FM2uN0

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'polls',
 'events',
 'django_evolution',
 'django_facebook')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/decorators.py" in wrapped_view
  98.             response = self.authenticate(self.fn, request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/decorators.py" in authenticate
  178.                 fn, request, graph=graph, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/decorators.py" in execute_view
  137.             result = view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/views.py" in connect
  40.         response = _connect(request, graph)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/views.py" in _connect
  81.                 request, connect_facebook=connect_facebook)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/connect.py" in connect_user
  89.                                       remove_old_connections=force_registration)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/connect.py" in _register_user
  250.     new_user = _update_user(new_user, facebook)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook/connect.py" in _update_user
  348.             image_field.save(image_name, image_file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  48.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  171.                 os.makedirs(directory)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  157.     mkdir(name, mode)

Exception Type: OSError at /facebook/connect/
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/images'
```

Comment: What is the value of your `MEDIA_ROOT`, assuming you're not using custom file storage system?